# Add versioning & company info to Mono DLL using Mono Compiler (mcs)

Tags: dll, mono, meta

I'm using MCS to compile some code into a DLL. Plain console compilation, no Visual Studio or similar. That works, the DLL works well.

But I'd also like to add some meta data to the DLL, so that (under Windows -> File properties) the company name and version etc. are visible.

I already tried around with .resx files, created some but that didn't help. Maybe I misunderstood the resx-thing.
The way I did it with the resx file: create a new text file, add the lines

```
# A list of personal data 
company=myCompany
```

So I guess that was wrong.

How can I add such meta data to my DLL?

Thanks, K1

Comment: You'd better follow the convention to put metadata into assemblies, not trying to build your own compiler. BTW, mcs just becomes obsolete. Everything is now Roslyn based.